# The type or namespace name 'Random' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dnx

I created a .NET 4.6 ASP.NET 5.0 Preview Web API project.

I use the Random class. I get 2 compile errors.

System.Random as assembly does not exist. In my code editor I can see Random and the type seems imported but still I get compile erros.

How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are using a unsupported framework.

Comment: What do you mean? I just created a project from the asp.net 5.0 preview template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the core framework, and it looks like it doesn't include the Random class. See the "Missing package message": you simply have to include the NuGet package: [System.Runtime.Extensions](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Extensions/4.0.10-beta-22816) (NOTE: it's beta, so you must use the Prerelease option to include this package in your project).

The new ASP.NET infrastructure is based on the .NET Core, to make it lightweight, and easy to support in other environments (like Mono, or Windows Phone). So, many things available in the full framework must now be added by using packages.

Comment: ah... I tried to add references but could not find System.Runtime... ok I could install it via nuget, BUT it does not compile because of this: => Unsupported;.NETPortable-wpa81+wp80+win80+net45+aspnetcore50 IPML.SERVICE.DNX Core 5.0 The problem here is asp.netcore50... So is there no Random class for asp.net core 5.0 ?

Comment: ok sorry. I did install Sytem.Runtime not Systen.Runtime.Extensions which is needed!

Comment: +1 - I find it helpful to use the Reverse Package Search when running into situations like this. For example: http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=Random - first hit is the System.Runtime.Extensions.